# Submenu text and background css not in sync

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress, divi

In the main navigation of our Wordpress website (made by the Divi Page Builder) we have two submenus. The submenu appears without a problem when you hover over the main navigation item, but the problem occurs when you leave the submenu. The background and the text disappear on two different moments.

I used some jQuery scripting for changing the appearances of the whole menu on scroll, but deleting the whole script doesn't fix the problem. So I think this is a CSS issue?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-website-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: (Might perhaps be as simple as different transition delays for different properties, or something similar.)

Comment: Please share code snippet of HTML, jQuery/Javascript and css here.

Comment: Thanks @Cbroe, that did the trick! And sorry for showing the website, wasn't aware this wasn't allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the transition property this is applied on the ul item as well as a inside li tag inside ul.

I am attaching the screenshot please try to comment it out or add transition to none to a element.

[image]

Comment: Great, that's the one! Didn't knew it would be this simple :). Thanks!